# Number Theory - How to solve equations like this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

$$\mathbf {n = 2^i + 5^j \quad\forall\;i,j\in \{0\}\cup Z^+}$$

I want to find all the ***n*** that satisfies this constraint within some interval say $\mathbf{[\alpha,\;\beta]}$ where $\alpha\;and\;\beta$ are some integers.

Comment: Then just let $i,j$ run from $1$ to $k$ and compute all $2^i+5^j$ in this interval. We have $n=7,9,10,12,15,\ldots,$.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to solve it other than trial, error, and common sense/experience with certain number patterns.

Comment: I'd do then $n - 2^i$ for $i = 0$ to $\log_2 i$ and so if any the results are powers of $5$.  Of course we'd need $2^i \equiv - n \mod 5$ and there's stuff we can do to rule out the $i$ to try.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I am looking for a more efficient approach

Comment: Why do you need a more efficient approach? And why do you believe there is one?

Comment: Oh, you want to *find* them!  Not solve for a particular one!.   Then just search as Dietrich Burde suggests is the most effiecient method.  You can limit your list as Ross Millikan suggest. $0 \le j \le \log_5 b$ and $\log_2(a - 5^j) \le i \le \log_2(b - 5^j)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can just search.  The greatest $j$ can be is $\lfloor \log_5 \beta \rfloor$.  For that $j$ the largest $i$ can be is $\lfloor \log_2(\beta -5^j)\rfloor$ and the smallest is $\max (0,\lceil \log_2(\alpha-5^j)\rceil)$  Now just count downward from the highest $j$, finding the range of $i$ for each.  Keep a list of the $n$s you find.  Sort it at the end, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it by trial and error.

Bear with me.

First of $2|n$ or $5|n$ then $i$ or $j$ (respectively) must be $0$.  And that will only have solutions if $n-1$ equals $5^j$ or $2^i$ (respectively).

Otherwise

Let $n \equiv k \mod 5$.

Then we need $2^i \equiv k \mod 5$.  Precisely one value of $m = 0, 1,2,3,$ or $4$ will be such that $2^m \equiv k \mod 5$ and $2^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

So we will just check all the values $i = 4v + m$ where $m \le 4v + m \le \log_2 n$.

Then we check whether $n- 2^i$ is a power of $5$.

So for example if $n = 11317$

$11317 \equiv 2 \mod 5$ and $2^1 \equiv 2 \mod 5$ so we only need to check $2,2^5, 2^9, etc.$

$11317- 2 = 11315$ and $11315$ and .....

Okay you know what.  I can "eyeball" multiples of $25=5^2$ and that will have a lot fewer things to check.

$11317 - 5 = 11312$ which is not a power of $2$ so if there is any solution $j \ge 2$.

$11317\equiv 17 \mod 25$ and $2^{20}\equiv 1 \mod 25$ and one of $2^{1 + 4m} \equiv 17 \mod 25$

$2^5 =16*2\equiv 32\equiv 7; 2^9\equiv 16*7 \equiv 112 \equiv 12;2^{13} \equiv  16*12 \equiv 32*6\equiv 7*6\equiv 42\equiv 17$.  So $i \equiv 13 \mod 20$.

$11317 - 2^{13} = 11317 - 8192 =3125$ which may be a power of $5$.  $3125 = 25*125 = 5^5$ so $11317 = 2^{13} + 5^5$.

And $\log_2 11317 =\frac {\ln 11317}{\ln 2} = 13.46... $ so we don't need to check any further.